# How to get the Model in my data access class library

Tags: c#, database, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

I want create a simple user interface with WPF Core. my goal is to save a few students in my database via the user interface. I have an extra class library for data access. This class contains simple CRUD commands with Dapper Micro ORM. I have a Student Model in my WPF Project. I don't understand how I can get my model into my class library without creating a dependency. I want to initialize my data access class in my MainWindow constructor. So my wpf project needs a reference to my class library.
But I need the student model class in my class library to save the results of the queries directly as a student, for example: con.Query < Student> ("SELECT * Students FROM MyDB). I would then have a circle dependency. Have anyone a easy Solution for my Problem?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.json"));

        IConfiguration configuration = builder.Build();
        DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess(configuration) //<- this class is from my referenced class library
    }
}
```

Comment: Pull your common objects into a separate class library that is referenced by both projects

Comment: i cant follow... if i create a seperate class library and reference both projects. What next? To instantiate the seperate class i need a reference in my wpf project. to inject my student model i would need a reference in the seperate class library to the wpf project. there is still a circle dependency or not? i guess im to stupid for programming. Or contains the seperate class a IStudent Interface or something? sry im new.

Comment: 3 projects, WPF, DataAccess, Common. Move the StudentModel class into Common. WPF references Common (for Model) and DataAccess (for CRUD). DataAccess references Common (For Model). StudentModel in Common can be used in both WPF and DataAccess, with no circular reference

Comment: @TheWorldDrown everyone starts somewhere, and its like "drinking from a firehose" at first, especially with WPF. Hang in there :)